# Xcode 4.5 build failed due to all framework is not found

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

This is second time I had this issue. 
I re-installed Xcode when I had this issue at first time, but I wondered what causes this problem.

None of project cannot be compiled due to all frameworks are not found.

Even though I started new project, Xcode complained about "Availability.h is not found". Once I got remove that line, it complained "UIKit/UIKit.h is not found", and so on.

Does anyone how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a plague in Xcode 4.5. If you go into build settings and switch build active architecture only to yes, I believe this will solve your problem